# AD users in different sites on a single Domain

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

I wanted to understand the best practices in setting up users in multi site - single AD domain scenario. Would it be possible to have users with the same username on the 2 different sites or is there a recommended way to set this up where a user is created in the primary site and is able to access when roaming on a workstation that authenticates with a DC belonging to another site.
thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a nutshell and simplified to a great degree:

All users belong to the same domain regardless of which site they're in.

Each user account in the domain should be unique.

Users can authenticate to any Domain Controller in the domain regardless of user or Domain Controller location.